# Absolute path in rosdep.yaml

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I would like to wrap an external library in a package. I want to download and build the code in  the same directory the package resides. Is it possible to find out the absolute path to the package in the corresponding rosdep.yaml script? If I try the bash command dirname in rosdep.yaml (i.e. echo "$(dirname $(readlink -f $0))") it gives the /tmp directory instead of the actuall directory in which the rosdep.yaml script resides. Im using ROS Electric under Ubuntu 11.04.

Thanks,
-Robert-

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12617/absolute-path-in-rosdep.yaml/) by [Robert Krug](https://answers.ros.org/users/1269/robert-krug/) on ROS Answers with karma: 225 on 2012-01-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the "rospack" command to find the location of your package. If your package's name is called "extlib" you would use:

```
rospack find extlib
```

---

Originally posted by [John Hoare](https://answers.ros.org/users/159/john-hoare/) with karma: 765 on 2012-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robert Krug](https://answers.ros.org/users/1269/robert-krug/) on 2012-01-12**:
That did the trick. Thank you!